# Can I cut out tensorflow object detection's images?

Tags: tensorflow

I wanna cut out tensorflow object detection's images.I am using tensorflow object detection's tutorial.My goal is to get images cut out detected parts.For example,if there is a image like [original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EMJC.png) ,I wanna transform into [ideal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bjy22.png)

Is there mark to cut out detected parts in tensorflow object detection API?What's procedure can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

When you run inference on Tensorflow Object Detection API, it returns bounding boxes in the format [ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax]. With these coordinates in hand , you can use OpenCV library to crop the ROI from input image.

Comment: thank you writing your answer.I want  to ask question to you, which is a file witten `[ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax]`? I searched the codes but I cannot find it.

Comment: Print output_dict['detection_boxes']